# XML file to html table (loop) C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following xml file and want to parse it into an .aspx table with c#. I already have a page with aspx and cs file. I have tried this and was getting an error. Any ideas. Thank you.
I also need to have each node to have a link to an html anchor where it can point to the item if possible.

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.Load(Server.MapPath("NewsSrc.xml"));
XmlElement root = Doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/News");
if (!IsPostBack)
{
Table tbl = new Table();
tbl.ID = "table1";
tbl.BorderWidth = 1;
this.Controls.Add(tbl);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
TableRow rw = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
var element = (XmlElement)node;
var Title = element.Value; //["Title"];
NewsItemTxt.Text = Title; //NewsItemtxt is label;
cell.Controls.Add(NewsItemTxt);
rw.Cells.Add(cell);
tbl.Controls.Add(rw); 
}
}
```

// and the xml file is //

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Edited by myself  -->
<News>
<NewsItem id="1">
<Title> news tile one </Title>
<Summary> this is summary to show ....</Summary>
<Details>details for this news</Details>
</NewsItem>

<NewsItem id="2">
<Title>test title </Title>
<Summary>sm line</Summary>
<Details> no details</Details>
</NewsItem>
</News>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest doing this on the client, not the server.

Comment: The error is on:  var Title = element.Value;

Comment: Okay, you've told us what line is throwing an error. **What's the error?**

Comment: check my updated answer, this works, all you need to do is use the variables title, description and details the way you want

Comment: @SeanThoman: Not that I disagree or agree with you, but what is your reasoning?

Comment: Next time you ask a question please include any errors or exceptions. Just saying "getting an error" doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it's using System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq, it should work but I can't guarantee it:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("NewsSrc.xml")));
foreach(var descendant in xmlDoc.Descendants("NewsItem"))
{
   var title = descendant.Element("Title").Value;
   var summary = descendant.Element("Summary").Value;
   var details = descendant.Element("Details").Value;
   var id = descendant.Attribute("id").Value;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that works nice. Any ideas how to do html anchor to each node/element. is there a way to call ID for example. thanks

Comment: @Fm3 I've added how you get the attribute value "id" in my answer as well, regarding anchor tags you can create a hyperlink control add the desired url along with the id values and insert it into a cell. also, since my answer helped you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes we are talking about an ASP.NET solution:

Perhaps you should look at [some tutorials on using an `XmlDataSource`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/XMLDataSource.aspx). Once your datasource is configured you could bind to a GridView/DataList control (or Repeater if you want more fine-grained control of the control output).

Comment: Can anybody just fix the code I have. i don't want gridview. thanks

Comment: since you haven't told us what error your are getting, no, we cannot "just fix your code."

Answer (score 0):

Until we know the error, here's a shot in the dark:

If the `NodeType` of that node is "Element" (from a brief glance at the docs, it seems likely that's what the `<Title>` tag would be considered), its `Value` property will be null. [As per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx):

> You can use the **XmlElement.InnerText** or **XmlElement.InnerXml** properties
>   to access the value of the element node.

See if that fixes it. Again, my best guess given we've no idea what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A simple sample to convert xml to html (table). You can use class css named 'xmlTable' to format the table created.

```
void Main()
{
    string s = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Scratch\Test.xml");
    string p = ConvertXmlToHtml(s);
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\Scratch\Test.html",p);
        
}

protected string ConvertXmlToHtml(string xml)
{
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder("<html><body><table align='center' " +
       "border='1' class='xmlTable'>\r\n");
    try
    {
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XElement root = xDocument.Root;

        var xmlAttributeCollection = root.Elements().Attributes();


        foreach (var ele in root.Elements())
        {
            if (!ele.HasElements)
            {
                string elename = "";
                html.Append("<tr>");

                elename = ele.Name.ToString();

                if (ele.HasAttributes)
                {
                    IEnumerable<XAttribute> attribs = ele.Attributes();
                    foreach (XAttribute attrib in attribs)
                        elename += Environment.NewLine + attrib.Name.ToString() +
                          "=" + attrib.Value.ToString();
                }

                html.Append("<td>" + elename + "</td>");
                html.Append("<td>" + ele.Value + "</td>");
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }
            else
            {
                string elename = "";
                html.Append("<tr>");

                elename = ele.Name.ToString();

                if (ele.HasAttributes)
                {
                    IEnumerable<XAttribute> attribs = ele.Attributes();
                    foreach (XAttribute attrib in attribs)
                        elename += Environment.NewLine + attrib.Name.ToString() + "=" + attrib.Value.ToString();
                }

                html.Append("<td>" + elename + "</td>");
                html.Append("<td>" + ConvertXmlToHtml(ele.ToString()) + "</td>");
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }
        }

        html.Append("</table>");
        html.Append("</body></html>");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return xml;
    }
    
    return html.ToString();
}
```